# How to Command-Tab to a specific Safari window running in full screen

Tags: macos, safari, application-switcher

I wish to switch between Eclipse IDE (not running in full-screen mode) and a tutorial running in Safari (in full-screen mode).

Whenever I <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> from Eclipse to Safari I am not taken to the tutorial in full screen mode but to a Safari page showing the message `Click to exit full screen`.

How could I move between the two without changing Eclipse to full-screen mode and without switching spaces using swipe on trackpad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You opened a tutorial video on YouTube in Safari which is running in full-screen mode. Now in the main YouTube player window, you have clicked on the **Full Screen** control placed towards the bottom right (of the player). This takes the YouTube video full screen, and moves it to a separate Space of its own.

When you use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to Safari, you land on the Safari window running in full-screen mode. You are shown the current Safari tab, but its full-screen video display is on another Space (generally, the next Space towards right of Safari's Space). This is the default behaviour in the described scenario.

After switching to Safari's Space, you'll have to change to the adjacent Space using any one of the methods to change Space. Since you mentioned you don't want to use trackpad, the easiest way to do so, is to use the keyboard shortcut to switch Space. To view/configure keyboard shortcut to switch Spaces, go to System Preferences app → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Mission Control.

The default shortcut assigned by macOS to **Move right a Space** is <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>. In my case, I have changed it to <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> is commonly used to move to end of line while editing text, which is a more frequent activity than moving to right Space.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Nimesh is correct, but I consider this very annoying default behaviour with no way around it. I would like to use Safari as my default browser, but for videos I use Firefox now, which does allow me to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> between its full-screen window and another application.

My use case is similar: watching a lecture in full-screen and quickly switching to my note-taking app with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Switching back to safari would pop up the **Click to exit full screen**, instead of the video, requiring me to constantly execute a second action (move a space).

Comment: I agree, this is very annoying, and answer by Nimesh is only partly a solution